# CUDNN not found running YOLO DARKNET

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, darknet

I am using this command for running darkent for object detection training in terminal

```
./darknet detector train cfg/voc.data cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg darknet53.conv.74
```

but, I have an error like this:

```
./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Hey, How did you solve the problem? I got stocked with the same error in Colab!

Answer (score 3):

I wish I could comment but I will have to use an answer to reply(not enough rep).

PJ Reddie's Darknet uses CuDNN if you set `GPU=1` in the Makefile. CuDNN is specific to nvidia GPUs. As in, if you do not have a GPU or do not have the Cuda Toolkit installed(and you do have a GPU), it will not work. If I am telling you something you already know, I would assume it is CUDA Toolkit installation that has gone wrong. Sorry if this is of no help.

I would try to reinstall it if you have a GPU and it is still not working. Look at the installation guide on Mr. Redmon's website for more details: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/

Comment: i really thank you for your response :) i solve that problem to set up route

Comment: i have more problem please help me


i trained data like that

./darknet detector train cfg/voc.data cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg darknet53.conv.74

but i have error like that

Error: You set incorrect value batch=1 for Training! You should set batch=64 subdivision=64

how could i do please give me some advice

Comment: @helpme if you have another problem please create a new question or edit this one if it‘s related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding this a little too late maybe, but for anyone with this error:

```
 Error: You set incorrect value batch=1 for Training! You should set batch=64 subdivision=64.
```

The problem is in cfg/yolov3-voc.cfg file. In the first lines you have to edit the batch size.